# Can I use ES6 modules (import export) to write webpack config files?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I started seeing:

```sh
(node:6420) Warning: require() of ES modules is not supported.
```

when starting my webpack build and was wondering if using all import export for `webpack.config.js` was supported yet.

edit 1: I want to know if it's supported without using @babel/register or other transforms

Answer (score 1):

Is is supported in Node 13. You can use either the .mjs extension (for files where you need to use import/export), or set "type": "module" in your package.json.

Comment: I will give this a try and report back

Answer (score 0):

If your code runs in Node, you can use the `fs` package to interact with the file system